# Rank in filtered data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like advice on how to create an order in column F according to the score of the points obtained in column E. This is so that the order must be according to the filter in column D (i.e. only visible data). Is there such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_F1` of your test sheet:*

```js
=ifna(vstack("Filtered_Order";index(rank(E2:E;filter(E:E;map(E:E;lambda(Λ;subtotal(103;Λ))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use helper column (you can hide it) with formula:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,E2)
```

Use this new column for rank formula:

```
=RANK(F2,F:F,0)
```

Result:

[image]